# Django ModelForm with ModelChoiceField and Query Filter

Tags: django, modelform

I need to create a list of cases in dropdown list from data passed into the form for the individual firm.

I pass the id into the form, but how do I use it in the CaseChoiceField query?

Just using id or self.id in the query does not work.

First in the view:

```
form = NewProjectCaseForm ( id = f.id )
```

The model form:

```
class NewProjectCaseForm ( forms.Form ):

    # get all the cases for the firm
    # how do I get the ID from below ???

    case = CaseChoiceField ( queryset = Case.objects.filter (firm_id = id ) )

    def __init__ ( self, *args, **kwargs ):

        # id from the view
        self.id = kwargs.pop ( 'id' )

        super ( NewProjectCaseForm, self ).__init__ ( *args, **kwargs )
        self.helper = FormHelper ()
        self.helper.layout = Layout (

        Div (
            Div ( 'case', css_class = 'large-10 cell' ),
            css_class = 'grid-x'
        ),

        ButtonHolder (
            Submit ( 'submit', 'Add Case', css_class = 'button small-6' )
        )
    )
```

to create the dropdown I use this:

```
class CaseChoiceField ( ModelChoiceField ):

    def label_from_instance ( self, obj ):
        return '{} - {}'.format ( obj.name, obj.firm )
```

I am using Crispy forms (for Foundation)

I hope this makes sense.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make use of `__init__` method like below.

```
self.fields['case'] = CaseChoiceField (queryset=Case.objects.filter(firm_id=self.id))
```

Now, The form looks like below

```
class NewProjectCaseForm ( forms.Form ):
    def __init__ ( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        # id from the view
        self.id = kwargs.pop ( 'id' )
        super ( NewProjectCaseForm, self ).__init__ ( *args, **kwargs )
        self.fields['case'] = CaseChoiceField (queryset=Case.objects.filter(firm_id=self.id))
        self.helper = FormHelper ()
        self.helper.layout = Layout (

        Div (
            Div ( 'case', css_class = 'large-10 cell' ),
            css_class = 'grid-x'
        ),

        ButtonHolder (
            Submit ( 'submit', 'Add Case', css_class = 'button small-6' )
        )
    )
```

Comment: AWESOME! thank you very, very much.  I never would have figured this out.